# AWS server retired; new instance lost access to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, node.js, amazon-s3, cdn

My old company has a system with a node.js front end running on an AWS EC2 instance. The instance was 'retired' yesterday morning, and I got a frantic call from the CEO because they were down.

I got onto the new instance and tried to restart it, and received this error:

```
CDN: Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames
```

Software configuration is completely unchanged as far as I can tell -- it's been about nine months since I've touched it. I've checked the AWS keys are configured, and they appear to be correct.

I attempted restarting with

```
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 npm start
```

just to see if it was something in the local config, or S2. Sure enough, I got past the exceptions, but now get a large number of messages of the form

```
unsuccessful upload of script "..." to S3
```

It's clear that the new instance can no longer access the S3 bucket, but I'm at a loss why.  Anyone have any ideas?